# How to print the entire page in react-to-print

Tags: reactjs, react-to-print

I have a print button that works great in react-to-print

```
     const handlePrint = useReactToPrint ({
         content: () => printRef.current,
     });

<div ref = {printRef}> this will print </div>
```

My question is how can I print the entire page and not just a single component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this same function to the parent component of the page.(Where all the code has written for the specific page to be print)

Comment: Thank you very much, and if the button is inside a child component and I want to print all the components that are inside the parent?

Comment: You can create function in parent component and pass by props in child component and then in child component place that props on button's onClick. it will work..
Here I am sharing a link of example with code for better visibility of my answer..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/infallible-fire-fcw5s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: let me know, this links works for you or not?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. The example is excellent. Arranged in a good way. Explained to me many things I had not settled with before